# AngularJS: Refactoring controller out of state

Tags: angularjs, refactoring

I've got an unnamed `Controller` embedded inside a `State` in Angular, and I'd like to reuse the code and templates so I can also use it for a state in a different URL. Is there a way to do this? Can I reference a `Controller` from another file?

Example of what I'd like to do: `states.js.coffee.erb`

```
#other state up here
        ])
  ).state('do-something',
    url: '/do-something/:id'
    views:
      'users':
        templateUrl: '<%= template_path('user-do_something') %>'
        controller: 'Controllers.SomethingController'
  ).state('other-state',
    url: '/other-state'
```

`controllers.js.coffee.erb`

```
angular.module("Controllers", [])
.controller('SomethingController', ['$scope', ($scope) ->
  $scope.variable_a = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do

```
controller: 'SomethingController'
```

You only needs to put the `Controllers` module as a dependency of the module where you are configuring your states.

```
angular.module('app', ['Controllers']).config(function($stateProvider) { .... });
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Can I pass an argument into the controller, or do I have to use it as-is?

Comment: Sure, research `resolve` where you can resolve stuff beforehand and pass it as a parameter to the controllers :)